# Inheriting from UIControl crashes when adding a property

Tags: ios, inheritance, swift

When inheriting from `UIControl` my app crashes as soon as I add a property to my `UIControl` Class and a hit test is performed (`EXC_BAD_ACCESS`) => E.g. mouse over the Control:

```
class ReloadButton: UIControl {

        var stopRotating: Bool = true


        init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!)
        {
            super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        }

        init(frame aRect: CGRect){
            super.init(frame: aRect)            
        }
}
```

If I remove the property `stopRotating` it won't crash. If I change the inheritance to `UIButton` instead of `UIControl` the crash won't happen.

Is there a specific function which needs to be added to `UIControl` to handle hit tests?

UPDATE: I created a minimalistic sample project on github: https://github.com/Aranir/hit_test

Comment: Can you post the stack trace so we can see where the bad access is happening?

Comment: Instead of a stack trace I created a minimalistic sample project to test out. It can be found on: https://github.com/Aranir/hit_test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the beta 5 Xcode the error messages have become more explicit.

Apparently the method

```
override init(){
    super.init()
}
```

needed to be implemented for it to work. This is now also necessary if the class inherits from `UIButton`